# AngularJS e2e test - $routeParams always empty

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

I'm trying to write an end-to-end test of my AngularJS app where I check that when a certain parameter is in the URL, something happens. However, `$routeParams` is an empty object. [This guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/UxSDCqDpTxo) had the same problem. I'm trying to determine that some text appears in the UI when `?code=whatever` is in the URL. My app works, and this route does what's intended:

```
$routeProvider.when '/',
  resolve:
    redirect: ($location, $routeParams, $http, $cookieStore) ->
      console.log $routeParams
      code = $routeParams.code
      console.log 'code: ' + code
      if code
        // do something
      else
        // do something else
```

When I visit `test-index.html?code=123` via the Karma test runner, in the browser console I see:

```
Object {}
code: undefined
```

I would expect to have to mock out `$routeParams` in a unit test, but I assumed an end-to-end test would function like the real app. Why is `$routeParams` completely empty in my test when there is definitely a URL parameter?

**Edit:** here is my test:

```
it 'fills in the input field when code is in URL', ->
  browser().navigateTo '/base/test-index.html?code=123#/'
  element('a.some-link').click()
  expect(input('my_param.value').val()).toBe 'something that gets set when code in URL'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$route`, `$routeParams` and most functions of `$location` are working on the part of url after "#". So, as in your example "/base/test-index.html?code=123#/", angular only sees "/" after "#", nothing else, that's why you got empty `$routeParams`. Also, you shouldn't use `$routeParams` in resolve function, use `$route.current.params` instead.

Try to change

```
browser().navigateTo '/base/test-index.html?code=123#/'
```

to

```
browser().navigateTo '/base/test-index.html#/?code=123'
```

And in your `redirect`

```
console.log $route.current.params
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels janky as hell, because I'm altering the actual to suit the test because AngularJS isn't filling out `$routeParams` like it should. Thanks to [this generic JavaScript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995/38743), I added `QueryString` to another JS file and included it in both my app index.html as well as test-index.html. Then, in my routes.js, I do `code = $routeParams.code || QueryString.code`. So if `$routeParams` is blank, which only seems to happen in a test, then the `?code=blah` parameter value is gotten via good ol' JavaScript `window.location` parsing.